# I'm Singaporean, my 90-day Schengen stay has expired. Can I transit via Zurich from Croatia to UK?

Tags: schengen, uk, transit, switzerland, croatia

I hold a Singapore passport but my tourist stay under the 90/180 Schengen rule has expired. I'm currently in Croatia (not under Schengen rule) and want to travel to UK (also not under Schengen rule) but the flight I booked will transit in Zurich airport. Will I be allowed to transit?

Comment: In what sense do you think that your “visa” has expired? Please note that as a Singapore citizen, you did not get a visa and that visa-free stays in the Schengen area work differently than, e.g. visa-waiver rules in the US. If you haven't stayed exactly 90 days in the Schengen area (e.g. you left after 80 days or spent 10 days elsewhere in the middle of your stay), you might still have the right to stay for a few days, even if it has been more than 90 days since your first entry. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule for details.

Answer (score 2):

If you are transiting in Zürich between two non-Schengen flights, you do not need to enter the Schengen area and the 90/180 rule should therefore be irrelevant.

The way I see it, the airline should let you board the plane based on your citizenship and would not usually check the length of stay requirement anyway. In Zurich, you should not see any border guard and even if you do, legally speaking, the 90/180 rule only becomes relevant when entering the Schengen area (at which point the border guards have to refuse entry and follow a specific procedure).